# Leaflet OSM Cross origin issue when zoom level > 19

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, cors

I am playing around a bit with Leaflet and run into an issue.

I am using the OSM tile service `https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`.

But I get CORS problem when I zoom in closer than level 19. Why do I get it only if I zoom closer than 19? Up to 18, it works fine. Shouldn't I get CORS issues on all zoom layers if it's truly a CORS problem?

Full error message

> Access to Image at
>   'https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/20/554563/283403.png' from origin
>   'http://localhost:4321' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4321' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Comment: Could you post the exact error message? Ideally from different browsers.

Comment: I added the full error message. Maybe its simply a limitation on the tile service?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the message!

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.
>
> The response had HTTP status code 404.

You got a "404 Not Found" error from the tile server because openstreetmap.org does not serve tiles on levels higher than 19.

openstreetmap.org does not include a "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header when returning a 404.

Thus your browser refuses to use the content of the error response any further.

Comment: Make sense, [https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=19/52.51863/13.37646](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=19/52.51863/13.37646)